# which one the best tools PHP either Bootstrap.?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4

To create dynamic pages for hosting purpose,what are the tools are required.

Comment: Please go read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic This is not a question fit for this site to begin with. (Plus, you’re comparing apples to oranges with asking about PHP vs Bootstrap, they have completely different purviews to begin with.)

Comment: PHP is a scripting language, while Bootstrap is library/Framework for designing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**PHP:-**
PHP is a server side scripting language used for creating dynamic web pages.
It uses an interpreter which is mostly run on a server.

**Bootstrap:-**
Bootstrap is an open-source HTML, CSS, JS framework developed by the team at Twitter with many components that let you create beautiful and modern web sites or web applications very fast.Also it is called Front-end-framework.

Bootstrap is a free collection of tools for creating a websites and web applications.

It contains HTML and CSS-based design templates for typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface components, as well as optional JavaScript extensions.